# Disable elastic scroll across browsers

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I'm wondering how I can disable the elastic/"pull" feature in all browsers. My understanding is that this is a MacOS UI detail. The problem is it's conflicting with my application logic. Hopefully there's a standard/accepted way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a setting at the OS level and you can't override that from a browser.

Comment: Really?! There MUST be something.

Comment: If nobody has an answer for you here, you might try apple's developer forum.